# event.dataTransfer and event.originalEvent are always null inside dragstart event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to create drag and drop directives for angularJS by following this post: http://jasonturim.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/angularjs-drag-and-drop/

But I can not send any data because inside the dragstart event handler `dataTransfer` and the `originalEvent` are always null.

My drag directive looks like this:

```
directives.directive('draggSrc', ['$rootScope', 'UuidService', function ($rootScope, UuidService) {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'A';

    directive.link = function (scope, el, attrs) {
        el.attr("draggable", "true");
        var id = attrs.id;
        if (!attrs.id) {
            id = UuidService.new();
            el.attr("id", id);
        }

        el.bind("dragstart", function (evt) {
            console.log(evt);
            console.log(evt.dataTransfer);
            console.log(evt.originalEvent);
            evt.dataTransfer.setData('text', id);

            $rootScope.$emit("DRAG-START");
        });

        el.bind("dragend", function (evt) {
            $rootScope.$emit("DRAG-END");
        });
    };

    return directive;
}]);
```

I have also called `$.event.props.push('dataTransfer')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to solve my problem I have switched from using jQuery's `bind` to using JavaScript's `addEventListener` and everything worked as expected:

```
directives.directive('draggSrc', ['$rootScope', 'UuidService', function ($rootScope, UuidService) {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'A';

    directive.link = function (scope, el, attrs) {
        el.attr("draggable", "true");
        var id = attrs.id;
        if (!attrs.id) {
            id = UuidService.new();
            el.attr("id", id);
        }

        el.get(0).addEventListener("dragstart", function (evt) {
            evt.dataTransfer.setData('text', id);
            $rootScope.$emit("DRAG-START");
        });

        el.get(0).addEventListener("dragend", function (evt) {
            $rootScope.$emit("DRAG-END");
        });
    };

    return directive;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue with a different fix: if you have an `alert()` or `confirm()` dialog in your drop handler, that clears out the `event.dataTransfer`.

Comment: 0
down vote

It is working for me. I tried whole day and finally this solution worked for me. Remove alert for your code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Similarly, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492200/57624 where `dataTransfer` is null when debugging in Firefox. (gah! - I spent at least an hour on this!)