# firefox ondrop event.dataTransfer is null after update to version 52

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, drag-and-drop

Introduction:

At about mid March 2017, after an update of firefox to version 52, certain functions - drop and paste - ceaced to function properly. As it shows up on debugging, the attribute "dataTransfer" of the event is nowadays set to null.

Previously to the update, onDrop and onPaste events both delivered the dataTransfer attribut set to the contents of what were to be dropped or pasted.

Questions:

How should drop and paste be handled with actual browsers?
Are there any precautions necessary these days?
Is there an explanation out there of the reasons behind the restrictive behavior of nowadays?

Is there any example out there in the internet showing how to accomplish the task with actual browsers?

I do not ask for examples prior to version 48 of firefox, since at least until that version, the whole thing worked flawlessly. I do not ask for examples with jQuery or any other library (while not rejecting those if they come as additional supplements). I do ask for examples with simple plain native javascript.

Comment: Experimenting with installations of older versions of firefox, the problem - ceasing of function on update to version 52 - is repeatable and stable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [event.dataTransfer.files is empty when ondrop is fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573710/event-datatransfer-files-is-empty-when-ondrop-is-fired)

Comment: Just wanted to share that I've setup a solution that I currently use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138942/drag-drop-api-and-table-rows-vanilla-js-only/62158007#62158007). The main issue for me that solved the problem consisted in the complete omission of the `dragleave` event, that just messed things up.. It's a solution I've made with an older ecmascript version, but the principle is still the same.

Answer (score 28):

When debugging step by step, the data from dataTransfer seems to get lost. Probably because of the events involved in debugging. Start the step-by-step debugging after the reading of dataTransfer (ev.dataTransfer.getData), and you will see that dataTransfer is not null anymore.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was about to give up and say firefox is just broken.

Comment: Without any debugging, dataTransfer is still null for Firefox 69 (64 bit)

Comment: Turns out calling alert() function within drop event also makes event.datatransfer null. Removing these made event.datatransfer work in Firefox 69 (64 bit).

Comment: @atomkirk the fact that running a function within a debugger and running the same function without debugger yield different results, fully qualify it for being broken.

Comment: Infact its very clever design, firefox is adding properties "on demand"

Comment: How has this been present, and annoying devs, *for 3 years* and still not fixed/well-documented?

Comment: Wow, good catch.  I would have never thought of that.

Comment: thanks for this one; but still a little incomprehensible to me why this is happening!

Answer (score 7):

With the latest version of FF (currently 73.0.1) `dataTransfer` appears as `null` only when debugging the drop event handler (that is, via breakpoint or `debugger` statement). Not debugging the function makes it work properly.

Answer (score 4):

I came across with similar issue.

We need to set few properties value to dataTransfer.

for example set **eventObj.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";** along with **eventObj.dataTransfer.setData("text",  "data");** in your dragstart function.

```
  function dragStart(eventObj) {
    eventObj.dataTransfer.setData("text",  "data");
    eventObj.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  }
```

you have to prevent default action of an element from happening. by using **eventObj.preventDefault();** and need to set **eventObj.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";**  in your dragover function like.

```
function dragOver(eventObj) {
    eventObj.preventDefault();
    eventObj.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
  }
```

In drop function also you have to stop default action otherwise firefox will open new page with whatever data you have passed in dataTransfer api.

```
 function drop(eventObj) {
    vardata = eventObj.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    eventObj.preventDefault();
}
```

I hope it will solve your issue in firefox.

**Happy coding**

Comment: After setting dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move"; in dragStart and dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move"; in dragOver function, dataTransfer is still null in dragDrop function.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue starting from the code on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop: the `dataTransfer` object was `null` so I was not able to access the dropped files: `event.dataTransfer.items;`

I have fixed the issue extracting the dropped files on the area before calling     `ev.preventDefault();`

Here my modified method:

```
function dropHandler(ev) {
    console.log('File(s) dropped');
    const _files = ev.dataTransfer.items;
    // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
    ev.preventDefault();

    if (_files) {
        // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
        for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
            // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
            if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
                const file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
                console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + file.name);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
        for (const i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
            console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed drag event with dragstart

```js
drag.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("key", "val");
})
```